# Multiple collapse using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, xslt

I would like to have a table which some of rows include another tables. My `html` file is as:

**HTML: Updated after answers**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Cell that spans two tables:</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <td>Rows including tables</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="4">Telephone:</th>
            <td>row1 of first table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="yellow">
            <td>
                <div class='yellowTable'>
                    <input name="yelInput" type="checkbox" class="toggle"/>
                    <label>
                        <span class='expand' id="mouse">
                            <span class="changeArrow arrow-up">-</span>
                            <span class="changeArrow arrow-dn">+</span>
                            row2 of first table
                        </span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="fieldsetContainer">
                        <table class="secondtable">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    20:00
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    hello world first table
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    21:00
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    hello world second table
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row3 of first table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="yellow">
            <td>
                <div class='yellowTable'>
                    <input name="yelInput" type="checkbox" class="toggle"/>
                    <label>
                        <span class='expand' id="mouse">
                            <span class="changeArrow arrow-up">-</span>
                            <span class="changeArrow arrow-dn">+</span>
                            row2 of first table
                        </span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="fieldsetContainer">
                        <table class="secondtable">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    20:00
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    hello world first table
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    21:00
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    hello world second table
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="red">
            <td>
                <div class='redTable'>
                    <input name="redInput" type="checkbox" class="toggle"/>
                    <label>
                        <span class='expand' id="mouse">
                            <span class="changeArrow arrow-up">-</span>
                            <span class="changeArrow arrow-dn">+</span>
                            row2 of first table
                        </span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="fieldsetContainer">
                        <table class="secondtable">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    20:00
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    hello world first table
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    21:00
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    hello world second table
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#mouse { cursor: pointer; }

.fieldsetContainer { height: 0;overflow: hidden;transition: height 400ms linear; }

#toggle { display: none; }

#toggle:checked~.fieldsetContainer { height: auto; }

label .arrow-dn { display: inline-block; }

label .arrow-up { display: none; }

#toggle:checked~label .arrow-dn { display: none; }

#toggle:checked~label .arrow-up { display: inline-block; }
```

But the problem is that the second collapsing does not work, it makes collapse the second first row rather than the second one.

I searched through the Internet about the problem, but I failed. How I could handle the problem?

By the way, I have added the complete code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/juoy75rg/63/) in jsfiddle.

**Update:**

thanks a lot for your great answers. Well as you mentioned I should change the `id`'s and `for` attribute of `<label>` which they should be unique. But not problem for is that I have thousands of such a tables and then I could not do it manually. I wonder if you please let me know if I could do systematically via CSS or JS. I will add them to the XSLT file. I can Thanks a lot again for your comments!

here is some lines from xslt file, related to the main point.

```
<tr class="yellow">
    <td>
        <div id="yellowTable">
            <input name="yelInput" type="checkbox" class="toggle"/> 
            <label>
                <span class='expand' id="mouse"> 
                    <span class="chnageSymbol expand-Negative">-</span>
                    <span class="chnageSymbol collapse-Positive">+</span>
                      <div> row2 of first table </div>
                </span>
            </label>
            <div  class="fieldsetContainer">
                <table class="secondtable" id="secondtable">
..............................

<tr class="red">
    <td>
        <div id="redTable">
            <input name="redInput" type="checkbox" class="toggle"/> 
            <label>
                <span class='expand' id="mouse"> 
                    <span class="chnageSymbol expand-Negative">-</span>
                    <span class="chnageSymbol collapse-Positive">+</span>
                      <div> row2 of first table </div>
                </span>
            </label>
            <div  class="fieldsetContainer">
                <table class="secondtable" id="secondtable">
..............................
```

(I have deleted end tags because of saving long question.)

**Update2:**

I am attaching JavaScript code for assigning `id`'s and attribute `for` as I've mentioned above.

**JS**:

```
function assignIdAndForAttribute()
{
    var redTable= document.getElementById("redTable");
    var redInputTag = redTable.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var redLabelTag = redTable.getElementsByTagName("label");
    //<![CDATA[
    for (var i = 0; i < tableError.length; i++) {
       redInputTag [i].setAttribute("id", 'toggleRed' + i);
       redLabelTag [i].setAttribute("for", 'toggleRed' + i);
    }
    //]]>

    var yellowTable = document.getElementById("detailedTable");
    var yellowInputTag = yellowTable.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var yellowLabelTag = yellowTable.getElementsByTagName("label");
    //<![CDATA[
    for (var i = 0; i < tableWarning.length; i++) {
       yellowInputTag [i].setAttribute("id", 'toggleyellow' + i);
       yellowLabelTag [i].setAttribute("for", 'toggleyellow' + i);
    }
    //]]>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set two ids that are "toggle" and both labels for "toggle". Change them to something else:

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="toggle2"/>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hvp6v3b8/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for for your answer. I wonder if you please let me know how could I give systematically id's with a counter or number after "toggle". Because my file is really large and I would like to do by XSLT file which fit the XML file and creates the above html file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How it looks like the code (or the part of it) that generates the html?

Comment: Please take a look at the update version. I have updated. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there a way that in the code where you create the html and attribute "toggle" id to the input and label you add also the iterator, like i (as index in for loop). Something like this:  for (let i = 1; i < myArrayLength; i++) {
      myHTMl = myHTML + '<input name="redInput" type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="toggle' + i.toString() + '"/> ';
 }

Comment: yes that can be for sure. I tried similar method, but it does not work for me. Can you please explain or post in your answer? Many thanks.

Comment: Could you post an exert of your code similar to mine above that generates the part of the html with 'input'. I might be able to correct it. I am not sure to have more to say than my last comment so my answer will be better...

Comment: I added JS function which it does not work for me! :(

Comment: Have you checked the modified html with browser's developper tools?

Comment: I have checked it. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I updated your code to the existing demo to work. Check it out : https://jsfiddle.net/spw0xqp9/

Comment: Thanks for your help! But the java script does not have and function name. And the id's is given implicitly which I want to assign them using JS as you mentioned. Am I right?

Comment: You have to adapt the js snipet from the demo (in script tag at the bottom) to your function in your js.

Comment: That code is for the demo html. Your actual html is little different so the js code from the demo needs to be a adapted to your actual html. But the essential logic is there

Comment: But I don't understand why the id's are not unique, as was your point in your answer. Because id's should be unique, right?

Comment: The html (file) doesn't change dynamically. but if you check in developper tools, you will see the generated html has new ids

Comment: I meant in the last link you've sent. But as you've mentioned, I could follow it in the developer tool. Many thanks.

Comment: If you still have issues, post a new question with code snippets and a reference to this question :)

Answer (score 2):

The error stems from the fact that you are using ids which are supposed to be unique. If you change toggle to a class instead of id, and update your css from `#toggle` to `.toggle` you'll almost have it.

If you don't hide the `input.toggle` elements at that point, you'll see it working fine.

The labels' `for` attribute will also need to be updated so you can interact with the label when you hine the input. Just use a unique id on each toggle to place in the `for` attribute of the label and use a class for styling and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Use same class instead of same id for toggle (as id has to be unique)
2. Use Opacity:0 instead of display:none (as it will be not available on DOM for events)

HTML:

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" />
```

CSS:

```
.toggle {
   opacity:0
}

.toggle:checked~.fieldsetContainer {
   height: auto;
}
.toggle:checked~label .arrow-dn {
   display: none;
}

.toggle:checked~label .arrow-up {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/juoy75rg/84/

Comment: Click next to + icon